# Foundation Orbit content slider not loading properly

Tags: zurb-foundation

When the slider loads all the content is stacked.

Please check the effect on http://smbsol.com/?lang=fr and switch between languages for example, you can see that the orbit content slider loads all the slides at once then puts them into a slider.

What would be a possible smart fix ?

Is there any way to not display the div until it finishes its loading?

Comment: I tried it in 3 different browser and it all loads ok? It is worth bearing in mind that all sliders images are effectively stacked...it is just js and css etc....that gives them the animation effects.

Comment: Are you sure ? maybe it does this on first load, but I've tried on many devices and even some website optimisation it is still showing all the slides at once on first load